# Pandas. New column based on missing values and column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that we have following df:

```
+---+---------+---------+--------+-------+
|   |  2016   |  2017   |  2018  | 2019  |
+---+---------+---------+--------+-------+
| 0 | 26560.0 | 26810.0 | NaN    | NaN   |
| 1 |   570.0 | NaN     | 550.0  | 540.0 |
| 2 |  3770.0 | 3450.0  | 3210.0 | NaN   |
| 3 |  4320.0 | NaN     | NaN    | NaN   |
+---+---------+---------+--------+-------+
```

I would like to add two additional columns 'value' and 'year'.
In 'value' column there will be value from the most recent year, and in 'year' column there should be a most recent year where there were no missing value:

```
+---+---------+---------+--------+-------+---------+------+
|   |  2016   |  2017   |  2018  | 2019  |  value  | year |
+---+---------+---------+--------+-------+---------+------+
| 0 | 26560.0 | 26810.0 | NaN    | NaN   | 26810.0 | 2017 |
| 1 |   570.0 | NaN     | 550.0  | 540.0 |   540.0 | 2019 |
| 2 |  3770.0 | 3450.0  | 3210.0 | NaN   |  3210.0 | 2018 |
| 3 |  4320.0 | NaN     | NaN    | NaN   |  4320.0 | 2016 |
+---+---------+---------+--------+-------+---------+------+
```

Could you please help me to solve it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new columns, first forward filling missing values per rows with select last column by position and for second get last non missing value by [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), but is necessary change order of columns by indexing:

```
df1 = df.assign(value = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1],
                year = df.notna().iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1))
print (df1)
      2016     2017    2018   2019    value  year
0  26560.0  26810.0     NaN    NaN  26810.0  2017
1    570.0      NaN   550.0  540.0    540.0  2019
2   3770.0   3450.0  3210.0    NaN   3210.0  2018
3   4320.0      NaN     NaN    NaN   4320.0  2016
```

Solution above working only if exist at least non mising values, for general solution use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for missing value if not exist val:

```
print (df)
      2016     2017    2018   2019
0  26560.0  26810.0     NaN    NaN
1    570.0      NaN   550.0  540.0
2   3770.0   3450.0  3210.0    NaN
3      NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN

mask = df.notna()
df2 = df.assign(value = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1],
               year = np.where(mask.any(axis=1), mask.iloc[:, ::-1].idxmax(axis=1), np.nan))
print (df2)
      2016     2017    2018   2019    value  year
0  26560.0  26810.0     NaN    NaN  26810.0  2017
1    570.0      NaN   550.0  540.0    540.0  2019
2   3770.0   3450.0  3210.0    NaN   3210.0  2018
3      NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN   NaN
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) also working if some row contain only missing values:

```
df2 = df.join(df.stack()
                .reset_index(name='value')
                .drop_duplicates('level_0', keep='last')
                .rename(columns={'level_1':'year'})
                .set_index('level_0')
                [['value','year']])
print (df2)
      2016     2017    2018   2019    value  year
0  26560.0  26810.0     NaN    NaN  26810.0  2017
1    570.0      NaN   550.0  540.0    540.0  2019
2   3770.0   3450.0  3210.0    NaN   3210.0  2018
3   4320.0      NaN     NaN    NaN   4320.0  2016
```

---

```
df2 = df.join(df.stack()
                .reset_index(name='value')
                .drop_duplicates('level_0', keep='last')
                .rename(columns={'level_1':'year'})
                .set_index('level_0')
                [['value','year']])
print (df2)
      2016     2017    2018   2019    value  year
0  26560.0  26810.0     NaN    NaN  26810.0  2017
1    570.0      NaN   550.0  540.0    540.0  2019
2   3770.0   3450.0  3210.0    NaN   3210.0  2018
3      NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN      NaN   NaN
```

Comment: @jezrael please look into below question during your free time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63355481/export-two-data-frames-as-one-excel-file-with-two-sheets-in-pandas-on-specified

Answer (score 1):

Other way using `pandas.Series.last_valid_index`:

```
def last_valid_value(series):
    ind = series.last_valid_index()
    return pd.Series([series[ind], ind])

df[["value", "year"]] = df.apply(last_valid_value, 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      2016     2017    2018   2019    value  year
0  26560.0  26810.0     NaN    NaN  26810.0  2017
1    570.0      NaN   550.0  540.0    540.0  2019
2   3770.0   3450.0  3210.0    NaN   3210.0  2018
3   4320.0      NaN     NaN    NaN   4320.0  2016
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `stack` with `groupby` and `last`

```
s = df.stack()


df1 = df.assign(
    value=s.groupby(level=0).last(),
    year=s.reset_index(1).groupby(level=0)["level_1"].last(),
)

print(df1)

      2016     2017    2018   2019    value  year
1  26560.0  26810.0     NaN    NaN  26810.0  2017
2    570.0      NaN   550.0  540.0    540.0  2019
3   3770.0   3450.0  3210.0    NaN   3210.0  2018
4   4320.0      NaN     NaN    NaN   4320.0  2016
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in df.index.values:
 for j in df.columns.values:
     if not pd.isna(df.loc[i,j] ):
         value=df.loc[i,j]
         year=j
 df.loc[i,"value"]=value
 df.loc[i,"year"]=year
```